# How to call Wi-Fi settings screen from my application using Android

Tags: android, wifi

Normally I am getting Wi-Fi setting screen on the emulator by clicking on the `Settings > Wireless controls > wifi settings`. I need to go directly to the Wi-Fi settings screen from my program when pressing on the Wi-Fi button which I have created. Contacts, Call Logs we can handle by using Intent.setData(android.provider.contacts...........). Is there any way to open settings sub-menus/menu from an android program?
Please give me advise or sample code on this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39111078/intent-to-open-wi-fi-direct-settings

Answer (score 177):

Look at [`android.provider.Settings`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html) for a series of `Intent` actions you can use to launch various settings screens (e.g., `ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS`).

**EDIT:** Add the coding line.

`startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));`

Comment: to be more specific,

android.app.activity.startActivity(new 
**android.content.Intent.Intent(android.provider.settings.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));**

or with proper *using*,

**startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));**

Comment: do you think `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` is [needed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13385550/281545) ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: Possibly. I can see where the Settings app might not handle these `Intents` properly when the Settings app is already in memory, but I haven't tried this specific scenario.

Comment: great, but I want to know what if I want to start `WIFI_SETTINGS` inside a popup window, do you have an idea about how to achieve that? thanks in advance

Comment: Don't forget to set android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE

Comment: to open general wireless settings use this: startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));

Comment: This has been an answer from almost a decade ago. But i just want to ask if it will be possible that the app's `Intent` call can control some configuration to how the WiFi settings, or to any other settings screen in general, will display? Particularly, I want to disable "home back button" that displays in WiFi settings of some devices. Mine is an old Sony Xperia M Android 4.1

Comment: @patrickjason91: "if it will be possible that the app's Intent call can control some configuration to how the WiFi settings, or to any other settings screen in general, will display?" -- not in general, and not using any documented extras.

Comment: On some device, you may encounter a "No Activity found to handle Intent" error, so don't forget to wrap your code in a try/catch block.

Comment: @CommonsWare, do you know if there's a way I can know if the use did indeed turned the wifi on? I'm using `startActivityForResult`, but I always get the same result for turning the wifi on or just pressing back. I can use `wifimanager.isWifiEnabled()` in `onActivityResult`, but I'm not sure this is the correct way.

Comment: @Keselme: Few, if any, of the `Settings.ACTION*` `Intent` actions are designed for use with `startActivityForResult()`. I would look at `WifiManager` and see what your options are there.

Answer (score 30):

example

```
ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) 
        getSystemService(MainActivity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
/*
 * 3G confirm
 */
Boolean is3g = manager.getNetworkInfo(
        ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnectedOrConnecting();
/*
 * wifi confirm
 */
Boolean isWifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(
        ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnectedOrConnecting();
if (is3g) {
    textView.setText("3G");
} else if (isWifi) {
    textView.setText("wifi");
} else {
    textView.setText("nothing");
    // Activity transfer to wifi settings
    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
}
```

Comment: to open 3G and WIFI settings use this: Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS

Answer (score 27):

Just have to call an intent with a context, 
try this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK));
```

Answer (score 11):

If you want to do it from the xml file:

```
    <PreferenceScreen
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:key="@string/setting_key"
        android:summary="@string/setting_summary"
        android:title="@string/setting_title" >

        <intent 
            android:action="android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS"/>
    </PreferenceScreen>
```

This will show an entry in your settings that will call the platform's settings activity

Comment: It works for me using `android.settings.WIFI_SETTINGS` action.

Answer (score 11):

If you're on Android 10, and your goal is to make the user to turn on the WiFi, you don't have to actually navigate to the Wifi settings screen anymore. You can use [Settings Pannel](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/features#settings-panels)

> an API which allows apps to show settings to users in the context of
> their app.

```
Intent panelIntent = new Intent(Settings.Panel.settings_panel_type);
startActivityForResult(panelIntent);
```

Answer (score 2):

**on button click click Listner**

> startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS), 0);

Answer (score 2):

Not all devices have same Wifi settings package name and class, I use this code to open the wifi settings page on most Android devices:

```
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings");
                intent.setComponent(cn);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ignored) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the code snippet to open wifi settings page**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings");
        intent.setComponent(cn);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity( intent);
```

Comment: didn't work in O I keep getting "android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.settings/com.android.settings.WirelessSettings}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
"

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented it like this in my app:

```
     if (Connectivity.isConnected(this)) {
                SERVER_IP = Connectivity.getIPAddress(true)
            } else {
                SERVER_IP = "Not Connected to Network"
                Snackbar.make(appRoot, "Not Connected to Network", 
                              Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                              .setAction("Open Settings") {
                   //open network settings
                  startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS))
                        }.show()
            }
        }


public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
        NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected());
    }
```