# Check WiFi and GPS isConnected or Not in Android?

Tags: android, gps, wifi

I would need to check the wifi is on or off in the phone at the runtime?

if it is not connected, i want to show dialog and goto directly Setting/Wireless Controls to enable it by user.

its for both wifi and **Gps staus** of the phone. How to do it? which intent to wake for this? Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) class to get the state of Wi-Fi.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318310/how-can-i-call-wi-fi-settings-screen-from-my-application-using-android) question for opening Wi-Fi settings. And this question for [GPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021176/android-gps-status) status.

Comment: how to trace the status of GPS?

Answer (score 11):

To check if the device is connected via mobile or wifi you can use this code:

```
ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

//mobile
State mobile = conMan.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState();

//wifi
State wifi = conMan.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState();
```

and then use it like that:

```
if (mobile == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || mobile == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING) {
    //mobile
} else if (wifi == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || wifi == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING) {
    //wifi
}
```

Comment: how to trace the status of GPS?

Comment: There's no guarantee that the mobile is networkInfo 0 and the wifi will be network info 1.  Might be better to check the type of what's returned by 'getActiveNetworkInfo'

Comment: 0 here means ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE, 1 - ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) 
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
    // ...
    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        t3.setText("The Internet is available");
    } else {
        t3.setText("internet is not available");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

//mobile
State mobile = conMan.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState();

//wifi
State wifi = conMan.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You might want to explain why your's is the better answer, rather than just post some code. Click the "edit" button to add further explanation.