# Android: How can we know the current connection type (ex. Wifi, 3G, 2G...) programmatically?

Tags: android, connection, wifi, 3g

I see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461227/how-to-know-device-is-connected-to-wifi-or-3g-programatically) but it could not help me much.

Comment: I just answered there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ConnectivityManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) and `getActiveNetworkInfo()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare getActiveNetworkInfo() is returning NULL for me in android 2.2(WIFI is enabled and am able to browse internet). Is there any solution?