# Finding the type of mobile connection in iOS

Tags: android, ios, mobile, connection

I am wondering if there is a way to find out the specific type of cellular/mobile connection in iOS. I need to know whether the user is on 3G/EDGE/GPRS so that I can store this information. I have looked into using the Reachability package but this seems to only differentiate between Wifi/WWAN connections and I need to know the specifics of the WWAN connection. Also, if anybody knows how to do this in Android also it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Apple iOS

Have a look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178636/way-to-discover-which-internet-connection-type-im-using-on-the-iphone), it seems to be a duplicate...

And as I wrote in the comments, it seems that's not possible without using private API.

## Android

Should be possible using [ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getActiveNetworkInfo()). By the way [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461227/how-to-know-device-is-connected-to-wifi-or-3g-programatically) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642267/android-how-can-we-know-the-current-connection-type-ex-wifi-3g-2g-progra) question seem highly related.

*EDIT*: deleted my old post which didn't really answer the question :-/

Comment: Hey Johannes, this seems to only let me differentiate Wifi/WWAN connections but I need to detect 3G/EDGE/GPRS when the connection is WWAN. Cheers.

Comment: Hey user708342, sorry I didn't read your question correctly :-/. I think that is now possible without private API...

Comment: No problem, so there is no way of finding this info out on either iOS or Android?

Comment: For Android, see "RF Signal Tracker" App.  For iOS, wish in one hand and spit in the other ... messy but accurate.