# Close the application if internet connection is lost

Tags: android

I want to check the internet connection constantly and close the app with a warning message if connection is lost. How can i manage to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461227/how-to-know-device-is-connected-to-wifi-or-3g-programatically

Answer (score 1):

Check Internet Connectivity via Phone Background service (such as AlermManager Service) then close the app if no connection found.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
close the app
```

Don't try to kill the process and its not recommended way of closing application. Either call finish() on all activities or call moveTaskToBack(true).

**For Solution
Here you go.**

You will need to register for and handle BroadCastReceiver `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`

**Step 1**

Include following permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**Step2**

Let Android know which class will be register for BroadCast Receiver.

```
<receiver android:name="ConnectivityReceiver_package_name.ConnectivityReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**Step 3**

Put your logic for various Network States.

```
public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     String action = intent.getAction();

    boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY,false);

     if(noConnectivity){

         //Show Warning Message
         //Close Application the way i suggested
     }

    }

}
```

Comment: I tried it but doesnt work when i close or open the internet connection. Shall i do something with "action" variable too? It seems to be unused.

Comment: put some logs in if(noConnectivity) {} block and check if control reached in block if you disconnect the internet.

Comment: Should i put ConnectivityReceiver in other classes as an inner class or something like that? Because I followed all the steps but it didn't work for me.

Comment: ohh i got some error in code i posted above...<receiver android:name=".receiver.ConnectivityReceiver"> should be changed to <receiver android:name="your_package_name.ConnectivityReceiver">