# Get check status 'Location consent' (WiFi & mobile network location)

Tags: android, gps, location, settings

in Setting > Location,

How can I know check status of 'WiFi & mobile network location'?

Click on this, show up 'Location consent' dialog.

[screenshot link](http://goo.gl/JMBHaX)

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311834/how-to-check-if-location-services-are-enabled) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973290/check-wifi-and-gps-isconnected-or-not-in-android) and a lot of other answers on `SO`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html) class to get the state of Wi-Fi.

Check [android.provider.Settings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html) for a series of Intent actions you can use to launch various settings screens (such as `ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS`)

So for `WIFI-Settings` you just have to add the following line

`startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));`

For `GPS` there is a detailed explanation on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021176/how-can-i-check-the-current-status-of-the-gps-receiver)