# Set Android IP,DNS,GATEWAY setting programmatically

Tags: android, set, wifi, ip

How do I set wifi ip address, dns address, gateway from android java i.e programmatically, I didn't find any method which has the capability to store the values.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can change system settings programatically.

First you need to request the 'WRITE_SETTINGS' permission in your 'AndroidManifest.xml':

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Then you need to actually change the setting using the following code:

```
    android.provider.Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_USE_STATIC_IP, "0");
    android.provider.Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_DNS1, "192.168.0.2");
    android.provider.Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_DNS2, "192.168.0.3");
    android.provider.Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_GATEWAY, "192.168.0.1");
    android.provider.Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_NETMASK, "255.255.255.0");
    android.provider.Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_IP, "1");
```

The current settings can be accessed via the same method but use 'getString' instead of 'putString'.

For information about the settings option visit the reference here:
[Settings.System | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html)

Comment: @Flexiweb, Bro. Its not working for Android OS Ver 3 & above. Can you please help for that too.

Comment: This may work for 'putString' but I am trying on 5.1.1 to 'getString' and it is returning null for every one of these.

Comment: Microsoft Defender is not using WRITE_SETTINGS permission and is able to change the DNS.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this from an application.

Would you like applications on your phone to change phone's settings at will?

Comment: yes i want my application to change wifi ip settings.. its not possible?

Comment: I think the point Peter is trying to make is that you shouldn't want arbitrary applications to change these settings.

Comment: ok, i wanna create an application that changes these n/w settings (ip,dns,gateway).. create different profiles of wifi config. and on single touch it changes the configruation..60% of my app has completed,just want a method or anything to change these settings

Comment: Yes we understand what you would like to do - it's not possible. Applications can't change phone settings.

Comment: i heard everything is possible in linux as well as android :))

Comment: Well there is some truth in this. You could use NDK - this gives you low-level access to Linux under Android. Warning: don't expect this to be documented or supported. They might even ban you from Android Market (I know I would). http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it will help but it's possible to manually set an alternative ip,gateway, dns etc for a particular access point in the Wireless settings. Whether you can do this automatically or using an intent is another question?

I just saw this which might be helpful

[How can i call Wi-Fi settings screen from my application using Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318310/how-can-i-call-wi-fi-settings-screen-from-my-application-using-android)

Comment: Thanks,by using intent is it possible to change wifi settings?

Answer (score 0):

android.provider.Settings.System.putString is deprecated now
this is the new method
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager
also i don't know how to use this new method, if someone knows that please learn it to me too

Answer (score -4):

the follow code can also do that:

```
    WifiManager mWifiManager = (WifiManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    DhcpInfo dhcpInfo = mWifiManager.getDhcpInfo();
    int dns1 = dhcpInfo.dns1;
    int dns2 = dhcpInfo.dns2;
```

Comment: How does this set the DNS value?