# Setting the IP address using DHCP programatically from my android application?

Tags: android, proxy, ip, dhcp

I am working on an a proxy based application where I need to edit the IP settings in an android Phone. I got reference from [Programmatically getting the gateway and subnet mask details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387036/how-to-get-gateway-and-subnet-mask-details-in-android-programmatically)

For getting DHCP Info this link is useful. Can I set a particular IP for the android mobile itself?

Comment: yes,you r rite.I need to set my ProxyIP for the gateway.Please give me some reference link.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So you want to actively change the IP address? This is not possible if DHCP is activated and no longer easily possible since Android 3.X.

Possible duplicate of:

[How to configue a static IP address, netmask, gateway programmatically on Android 3.x or 4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278461/how-to-configue-a-static-ip-address-netmask-gateway-programmatically-on-androi)

[Set Android IP,DNS,GATEWAY setting programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106502/set-android-ip-dns-gateway-setting-programatically)