# Change DNS programmatically in Android

Tags: java, android, android-networking

I'm writing an app to change the DNS of my Android device.
I've successfully gotten the current DNS info out, I can't however figure out how to set it to the new values.

I've tried the following approach:

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putString(v.getContext().getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_USE_STATIC_IP, "192.168.100.102");
android.provider.Settings.System.putString(v.getContext().getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_DNS1, "192.168.0.2");
android.provider.Settings.System.putString(v.getContext().getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_DNS2, "192.168.0.3");
android.provider.Settings.System.putString(v.getContext().getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_GATEWAY, "192.168.0.1");
android.provider.Settings.System.putString(v.getContext().getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_NETMASK, "255.255.255.0");
android.provider.Settings.System.putString(v.getContext().getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_IP, "1");
```

Didn't seem to change anything though.

(*I'm sure the values I'm inputting aren't correct - as of now I just want to see some changes in my settings*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add the permission? [[Link]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106502/set-android-ip-dns-gateway-setting-programatically)

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>`