# Change DNS servers of WIFI connection

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm working on an app that needs to change DNS servers on an active Wi-Fi connection.

I get `WiFiConfiguration` object of active `WiFi` connection and I know about `linkProperties` property of Java's `WiFiConfiguration`. But Mono's `WifiConfiguration` does not contain this feature; as it can get around this situation?

Comment: I don't think you are able to do that. It would be a security issue in my opinion. But you can use proxies in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API for that, but you can use reflection to do the hack. There is no guarantee that this will work

```
public static void setDNS(InetAddress dns, WifiConfiguration wifiConf)
    throws SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException{
        Object linkProperties = getField(wifiConf, "linkProperties");
        if(linkProperties == null)return;

        ArrayList<InetAddress> mDnses = (ArrayList<InetAddress>)getDeclaredField(linkProperties, "mDnses");
        mDnses.clear(); //or add a new dns address , here I just want to replace DNS1
        mDnses.add(dns); 
    }
```

Comment: The documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html) contains property WIFI_STATIC_DNS1. In android 2 could use it to set the DNS server (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106502/set-android-ip-dns-gateway-setting-programatically). But this property is deprecated in api17. Google recommends using WiFiManager

Comment: I tried it through reflection before - but Xamarin not allowed to do so (don't allow modify object's fields). Moreover, it is an unreliable method and for program for many people hardly acceptable....