# Change DNS programmatically (for both Sim Network/ Wifi) | Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dns, android-10.0

I want to change the dns for both mobile network or wifi using my android app. I have found few solution but they are not working for me as the are now deprecated.

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106502/set-android-ip-dns-gateway-setting-programmatically)

Problem in solution one is that **android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_DNS1** is deprecated now.

[Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278461/how-to-configure-a-static-ip-address-netmask-gateway-programmatically-on-andro)

In solution 2 one answer is marked as working solution but now read fails for me also failed for other users read comments section of that answer.

Also I want to configure DNS for both mobile and wifi network. So, I need a solution that should work for at least API level 29.

> I just want to change dns (mobile data/ wifi) without routing device.

Comment: Found any solution?