# Change and Set DNS Setting via App in Flutter for IOS And Android

Tags: flutter, shell, dns

Is there any package for this to change dns setting directly.
Thank You

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: You can create your own plugin to resolve this issues . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106502/set-android-ip-dns-gateway-setting-programmatically