# How to move "onClick" from a button to the wifi settings

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

i would like to have a button that on click will direct the user to the wifi settings of the device..any idea for the onclick code please?

Comment: Have a look at this [question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2318310/512958)

Comment: all the answers are right!!thanks mates!

Answer (score 3):

You can star the WIFI Settings activity with:

`startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));`

Comment: instead of posting a same answer one can vote up the already posted answer.
Its a battle of reputation but make it fair...

Answer (score 3):

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
```