# Android link to wireless & Network Settings

Tags: android, android-wifi

Hi I'm making an App that checks internet connection, if it's not connected it goes to an activity that has an error message and a button that I want to link to the wireless and network settings. But I'm not sure how to do it, can anyone help me ?
Here's what I've got so far.

```
public class NetworkActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.networkact);
        Button settings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_settings);
        // Listening to button event
        settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Starting a new Intent
                Intent gotoSettings = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(gotoSettings);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

At the moment it goes to another activity but I want it to go to the wireless & network settings.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318310/how-can-i-call-wi-fi-settings-screen-from-my-application-using-android

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I believe, what you want is this:

```
btn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.ButtonNet);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 10):

If you use Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS then user can go in both settings mobile network and wifi.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for open page mobile network

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS));
```