# Access WiFi settings programmatically in Android 4.0.3

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-wifi

I know the method how we access WiFi settings, it is achieved through code below -

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
```

However, when I used it in android 4.0.3, it lead me to 'wireless configuration settings' page where I couldn't find 'turn on/off Wifi button'. As it is outside that wireless configuration page.

How I could achieve it? I am testing on Samsung Galaxy S2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
```

Comment: Apologies for dropping by late, your solution is precise, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a good thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318310/how-can-i-call-wi-fi-settings-screen-from-my-application-using-android), maybe it help you

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
```