# LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation returns null when it runs just after system booted

Tags: android

my appwidget gets location to get forecast.
as title, cant get location at just after system rebooted.

```
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false); 
    criteria.setSpeedRequired(false);   
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);    
    String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    double lat = loc.getLatitude(); //null
    double lon = loc.getLongitude();/null
```

why these are null at just after system rebooted?

Comment: May be because both GPS and Data Connections is not ON?

Comment: oh! you are right.i use boadcast.

Comment: shall i post it as an answer ? then you can mark it as an answer to help others

Comment: if answer usefull, please upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because on Boot up both GPS and Wifi/Data Connection is `OFF`.So,location is null.
You need to change a bit of code which can prompt the user to open [**GPS Settings**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021176/how-can-i-check-the-current-status-of-the-gps-receiver) or [**Wifi Settings**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4668583/1221203).

Answer (score 1):

Using `Broadcastreceiver on reboot`

```
// Do something onReceive()

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

//Do something after reboot
}
```

See this link:

[Android BroadcastReceiver on startup - keep running when Activity is in Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290141/android-broadcastreceiver-on-startup)