# How can I get to WIFI Direct Screen by code in Android?

Tags: android, wifi-direct

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318310/how-can-i-call-wi-fi-settings-screen-from-my-application-using-android) answered the question about going to WIFI setting screen. However, I would like to direct the user to WIFI Direct screen when its exists on a device. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard `Intent` structure to go to a Settings screen related to WiFi Direct.

Comment: Any other means to reach Wifi direct screen?