# App force closes after opening WiFi settings

Tags: android, onclick

I want my app to open WiFi settings on button click but when I do so, it force closes. This is my code:

```
public class Settings extends Activity {

    private static Intent ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.settings, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void click(View view) { 
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);  
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

The XML Layout:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Settings" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp" >
    </RadioGroup>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:onClick="togglewifi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Toggle Wifi" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radio0"
        android:text="Toggle Data" />

    <Button
        android:onClick="click"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Configure" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Done" />

     </RelativeLayout>
```

LogCat:

```
12-22 12:29:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(2813): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-22 12:29:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(2813): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
12-22 12:29:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(2813):     at     android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
12-22 12:29:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(2813):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
12-22 12:29:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(2813):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
12-22 12:29:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(2813):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-22 12:29:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(2813):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Check permission in android AndroidManifest.xml and also post log error.

Comment: please dont vote down , i have posted the logcat

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318310/how-can-i-call-wi-fi-settings-screen-from-my-application-using-android

Comment: @Anonymous can you post xml also

Comment: @Anonymous `ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS = null;` fix it

Comment: if i remove it it says it cannot be initialized please fix my code

Comment: Why aren't you using `android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS` ?

Comment: And what is the need to create radio group? you are not grouping any buttons in it.

Answer (score 1):

You do realize that you are setting the Intent action to null. When you execute your click method it would of course get an NPE. Fix that.

Answer (score 0):

In your XML, you declare an `onClick` callback on the `RadioButton` `radio0`:

```
android:onClick="togglewifi"
```

but your `Activity` does not have a method `public void togglewifi(View)`, causing the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
     at     android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
```

Comment: @Anonymous Yes and the activity has no method for `togglewifi`

Comment: in class file -"click"

Comment: in xml in radio button you are using  android:onClick="togglewifi". but you are not implementing wifi method in your activity.

Comment: android:onClick="click" check button first then talk

Comment: Yes there's that and there's also `android:onClick="togglewifi"`. I copy-pasted it from your question.