# Intent to open Wi-Fi Direct settings

Tags: android, android-intent, android-wifi, wifi-direct

To open the WI-FI settings the code is:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
```

To open the **WI-FI Direct** settings the code is ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the manifest for that activity on KitKat,

```
    <activity android:name="Settings$WifiP2pSettingsActivity"
            android:taskAffinity="com.android.settings"
            android:parentActivityName="Settings$WifiSettingsActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE_LAUNCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="com.android.settings.FRAGMENT_CLASS"
            android:value="com.android.settings.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pSettings" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.android.settings.TOP_LEVEL_HEADER_ID"
            android:resource="@id/wireless_settings" />
    </activity>
```

So it doesn't look like they exposed an explicit intent. You may be able to start it via `ComponentName` but the name is not guaranteed to be the same across Android releases.