# Is there a way to open Wifi activity in android and get a result for successful connection in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-settings

So here is my scenario ,
I want the user to click a button which takes him to the wifi networks screen using

```
startActivityForResult(Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS),RESULT_CODE);
```

The user then selects a wifi network ,connects to it and the wifi setting activity closes and the user lands back into my application.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: You might find what you're looking for here: [How to call Wi-Fi settings screen from my application using Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318310/how-to-call-wi-fi-settings-screen-from-my-application-using-android)

Comment: But this doesn't answer my question of how to return back to the activity by connecting to a particular network

Answer (score 3):

android.provider.Settings gives Intent actions you can use to launch various settings screens (e.g., ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS).

To work with button you must write:

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
         startActivity(intent);
      }
});
```

For getting wifi connected callback,  you must put permissions in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

And put this code in activity onCreate or some method:

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) 
   getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 

NetworkRequest.Builder builder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();

connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(builder.build(),   
   new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() { 
   @Override 
   public void onAvailable(Network network) { 
      //Do your work here or restart your activity
      Intent i = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
      i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
         Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
      startActivity(i);
   } 
   @Override 
   public void onLost(Network network) {
       //internet lost
   }
});
```

Comment: I am able to do that already ... What I want to achieve is that the user should select a wifi network and the wifi activity should close after that thus returning the user to the app.

Comment: I will try this and let you know

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
```